# Power for 1 Device, 1 MCU, and 2 modules

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, power, dc-dc-converter, ac-dc

I have four things I need to get power to. The first is a device that needs 48V and 30W. The other three include an MCU and two modules. Each have various pins that need either 3.3V or 1.2V. I’ve drawn up a circuit on how to get power from a wall into these four things, but I’m not sure if what I did is completely correct, and I could use some guidance.

[image]

Comment: Did you calculate the output voltage of your voltage divider, considering that the MCU and module2 are in parallel with the 1K resistor?  I bet you did not.

Answer (score 0):

If 3.3V , 1.2V is used for any analog , you may want an LDO from 5V DCDC or special RLC filters on 3.3V DCDC + ferrite snubbers.

1.2V needs an LD0 from 3.3V for regulation.

Since LV uses only 1W, no issues other than glitch clamping diodes, shielding from high power Flyback. and balanced shielded analog inputs.